# Testing the same cases in a method called from different method in a Unit Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have a private service method that is called from create and update methods in the same service. Normally we do not write Unit Test directly for the private method and I write the case in the method that calls this service method.

At this stage, I am confused that; I write all the test cases for the private method in the tests for create method.

**1.** In this scene, should I omit the same case for the private method when I write test method for the update method? Because in this case it seems to be writing redundant tests for the same case (calling it from create + calling it again from update method).

**2.** On the other hand, I am also thinking of that if I remove create or update method in the future, then calculate method tests will be removed. In this case, it may be better to write test cases related to calculate method in both of create and update methods.

Any idea regarding to this issue?

Here is a sample code if you need to explain something based on this scenario:

```
public void create(EmployeeRequest request) {
    // code omitted

    calculate();
}


public void update(UUID uuid, EmployeeRequest request) {
    // code omitted

    calculate();
}
```

```
private void calculate() {    
    // code omitted
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, the private methods are before all the details of the implementation.

You should test your two methods

Comment: Do you mean that I can repeat the same test cases belonging to the same private method in create and update methods even if it seems to be redundant??? Any idea?